# Laravel Application in production don't login in Chrome, Safari and Edge but does in Firefox

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I deploy a Laravel Aplication with Laravel 8 (is in producction), but, when I login using Chrome, Safari, Edge, an error 419 shows. But in Firefox don't show. I find other answers and everybody says "check csrf" but, the form have it.

Here the Login Form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                @csrf
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input placeholder="Correo electrónico" id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>               
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @error('email')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                 @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input placeholder="Contraseña" id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">                
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @error('password')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8">
                  <div class="icheck-primary">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                    <label for="remember">
                      Recuérdame
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-4">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{{ __('Entrar') }}</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
              </div>                  
            </form>
```

and the .env file

```
APP_NAME=theproyect
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:1ZRWjL3Of6m57zKh5sUvfUkW2kzo5vIjOmttnp0dboE=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://mydomian

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=thedatabase
DB_USERNAME=theuser
DB_PASSWORD=thepassword

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

and the config/session.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

   
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),


    'lottery' => [2, 100],

  
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),


    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),


    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),


    'http_only' => true,

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the HTML markup is missing a closing `/>` tag and is therefore invalid:

```
<input placeholder="Correo electrónico" id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
```

Any IDE should show this line in red ...

Comment: I fixed it, but continue with the problem. Isn't that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper permission on `storage`:

```
chmod -R 755 storage
```

If this didn't work, consider clearing the cache. Application cache can also lead to session expiration error. This can be for browser cache too. You can clear the cache like this:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Note that,

> This will clear all the cache data in storage.

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: And how is this answer related to the error message?

Comment: @MartinZeitler He's using file session driver as `SESSION_DRIVER=file`. Invalid cache or permission error on `storage/framework/sessions` could be the problem. plz correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @amirz98 sorry, doesn´t work. I forgot explain it´s run on chrome local, but in my domain, on server, doesn´t. Also I check the permission on `storage` and have 755

Comment: @amirz98 you mentioned `SESSION_DRIVER=file` i'm new in laravel so I don't know many things. What's the meaning of that?

Comment: @RobertoVargas check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#configuration) about session driver. Try testing on chrome incognito to see what happens.

Comment: @amirz98 I tried, I failed. I have to attach another file for you see?

Comment: @RobertoVargas How about `php artisan key:generate`? (on your public server)

Comment: @amirz98 I can't do that, the server is a webhosting just like Cpanel, and I can (or I don't know) run command on it. I have to run locally and then upload it.

Comment: @RobertoVargas That is probably the cause. People having this problem for a long time. Using Laravel on shared hosts.

Comment: @amirz98 so,  I'm not have any options? what about if I save the sessions in a table at database?

Comment: @RobertoVargas I didn't mean that. There should be some workaround on this.